# How to change echo output if output equals 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, css, datetime

I want my website to output "Unknown" if the timestamp is equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 How would I do that? Here's my code:

```
<h1>Exabit URL Shortening Service</h1>
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM links");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<p>"; echo "ID: "; echo $row['id']; echo " URL: "; echo $row['url']; echo " Created on: "; echo $row['created']; 
      echo "</p>";
      }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Exabit URL Shortener Database</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}
p {
padding:2px;
border:1px solid white;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color:white;
text-align: center;
right: 8px;
left: 8px;
}
h1 {
color:white;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance,
Zack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $row['created'] should be a string, just check it:

```
if ($row['created'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
    echo "Unknown";
}
else {
    echo $row['created'];
}
```

**OR**

to out put it in one line with your code you could do this

```
echo ($row['created'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") ? 'Unknown' : $row['created'];
```

Comment: Hmm... That didn't work..

Comment: What was the result, specifically?  Did nothing echo, or did the timestamp echo even though it was '0000-00-00 etc', or what precisely?

Comment: It worked, I made a mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @ZackDavies  Don't forget to accept the answer, please!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if the return timestamp i think this is how it checked

```
if ($row['created'] > 0) {
    echo $row['created'];
} else {
    echo 'UnKnown';
}
```

**OR Inline IF**

```
echo ($row['created'] == 0) ? 'Unknown' : $row['created'];
```